# Disable \FloatBarrier for selected sections

Tags: floats, sectioning, placeins

I am using `\usepackage[section,above,below]{placeins}` which does exactly what I want. In order to avoid too many blank pages, I am looking for a command that disables the `\FloatBarrier` at the following `\section` beginning. Is this possible?

Consider this example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[section,above,below]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Only chapter}
    This very short introduction leaves most of the page empty...
% ---- HERE, A PAGE BREAK OCCURS ----
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{heading}\label{key}
    \end{figure}
    \section{My section}
    This page break is annoying!
\end{document}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler not to use the `section` option and just use floatbarrier if neeed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: generally yes but in >90% of the cases I want a '\FloatBarrier ' which is why I came up with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just save the original section command before `placeins` alters it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\origsection\section
\usepackage[section,above,below]{placeins}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\show\section
    \chapter{Only chapter}
    This very short introduction leaves most of the page empty...
% ---- HERE, A PAGE BREAK OCCURS ----
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{heading}\label{key}
    \end{figure}
    \origsection{My section}
    This page break is annoying!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `section` option of `placeins` basically turns `\section` into:

```
\FloatBarrier\section
```

[David's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303448/64454) aims at locally go back to the initial definition of `\section`.

Here is another approach. It locally disables `\FloatBarrier`'s effect instead:

```
\let\saveFloatBarrier\FloatBarrier% save the original command
\let\FloatBarrier\relax% disable FloatBarrier's effect
\section{My section without float barrier}
\let\FloatBarrier\saveFloatBarrier% restore FloatBarrier's original definition.
```

I prefer this approach, since it doesn't fiddle with `\section`'s definition, you continue to use the regular `\section` command (what makes syntactical highlighting and IDEs keep track of the sectioning), and all redefinitions are located where it as takes effect (i.e. close to the `\section` macro, and not in the preamble).
However, this approach is more verbose and less compact - especially if you intend to use is multiple times (where  David's answer solves the problem once and for all).

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[section,above,below]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Only chapter}
    This very short introduction leaves most of the page empty...
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{heading}\label{key}
    \end{figure}

\let\saveFloatBarrier\FloatBarrier
\let\FloatBarrier\relax
    \section{My section}
\let\FloatBarrier\saveFloatBarrier
    This page break is annoying!
\end{document}
```